# How can I define a vectroized function to make a list of 2 by 2 matrices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I'm trying to define a function that return a 2 by 2 matrix. Specifically, I have:

```
def f(d,n):
    return scipy.mat([[1,d/n],[0,1]])
```

This works fine when d and n are scalar input. But if d and n are vector input this function doesn't work. I don't know how to vectorize this function; for example, I'd like to make a function f that does the following:

suppose

```
d=[1,2,3,4]
n=[5,6,7,8],
```

`f(d,n)` returns an array of 4 matrices:

```
[[[1,1/5],[0,1]],[[1,2/6],[0,1]],[[1,3/7],[0,1]],[[1,4/8],[0,1]]]
```

It would be super awesome if you can let me know if this is possible!! Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need an array of `matrix` instances?  A 3-D numpy `ndarray` (i.e. the basic numpy array class) would probably be simpler.